# NSTimer where code repeats every (some time value in seconds) for 1 minute

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nstimer

I have read some docs on NSTimer and havent quite seen what I am looking for.

I would like to know how to write an NSTimer which will repeat every 1 sec or another time value(maybe have this value as parameter) and the overall repeat should repeat for one minute.

Also how is this overall time (1 minute) shown on screen , maybe in a UILabel?

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at my answer on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220695/nstimer-problem/3220828#3220828 It's very similar to what you are asking for.

Comment: That is awesome thanks. What if I wanted to have a pause button, how will the timer be paused?

Comment: Basically, you would invalidate the timer (and set the ivar to nil) in your pause action and schedule a new timer in your resume action.  In these cases you wouldn't want to reset the "remainingTicks" value.

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly what NSTimer does. You need to invalidate the timer yourself after a minute has passed though. Just keep count of the number of invocations and when you hit 60 you invalidate the timer.

[NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSTimer/scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:invocation:repeats:)

[NSTimer Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Timers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000061i)