# NSTimer countdown with label to show time left

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nstimer

I need help for my app. I dont know how to use a `NSTimer` in my app, and also don't know how to make the value of time left display on a label. Also, is it possible to get a list of processes and use radio buttons to select whether to hide or kill a process after the timer is up?

Comment: To answer the latter part of your question: no.  You can access current processes (sort of), but you can't kill them.

Comment: Please clarify your question: Are you targeting Mac or iPhone? Are you talking about processes in the context of the OS or a list of concurrently running tasks within your application, (e.g. background downloads) that you want to (or already do) keep track of, in order to possibly cancel them? This means all the difference for answering the second part of your question… Regarding its first part: Apple's documentation is — at least most of the time — _very_ good! Learn to find your way around in it; it will pay off quickly. Also: For UI stuff, poke around the class-library in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this might be a good read: **[Using Timers](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Timers/Articles/usingTimers.html)**

Finally, this answer should do exactly what you're asking for.  With a little more searching you would have found ***[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220695/nstimer-problem/3220828#3220828)*** question.

Answer (score 0):

An NSTimer is going to call your method at a regular interval - you can set this up to a 1 second period and decrement each tick.  Or, to be more reliable, you can have it run more frequently and handle actual POSIX gettimeofday() to track time yourself and figure out the time remaining

And yes those things are possible.  For radio buttons you would simply get their state and act upon that however you like.  You can set them up to tell you when they change, or when you do your specified behavior you can check their status.