# Auto Saving the content of the screen to the database

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am developing an iPAD application and I want to auto save the contents of the form into SQLITE in every 10 sec intervals. Right now if I press the save button then it saves to the database. Is there any way to auto save the whatever I am writing in the form in every 10-15 seconds. Help me out with this.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSTimer and perform the save every x minutes. The code will look something like this. It is a modified version of the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3220828/92117).

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController
{
  @private
  NSTimer * countdownTimer;
  NSUInteger remainingTicks;
}

-(IBAction)doCountdown: (id)sender;

-(void)handleTimerTick;

-(void) saveData;

@end

@implementation MyController

// { your own lifecycle code here.... }

-(IBAction)doCountdown: (id)sender
{
  if (countdownTimer)
    return;


  remainingTicks = 60;
  [self saveData];

  countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target: self selector: @selector(handleTimerTick) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void)handleTimerTick
{
  remainingTicks--;
  [self updateLabel];

  if (remainingTicks <= 0) {
    [countdownTimer invalidate];
    countdownTimer = nil;
  }
}

-(void) saveData
{
  //Save your data here
}


@end
```