# set NSTimer time to NavigationBar label

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, nstimer

I want to display remaining time from my NSTimer in NavigationItem title, that's why I can't create outlet for it.
My code is from this question [NSTimer problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220695/nstimer-problem/3220828#3220828):

```
@interface MyController : UIViewController
{
UILabel * theLabel;

@private
NSTimer * countdownTimer;
NSUInteger remainingTicks;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel * theLabel;

-(IBAction)doCountdown: (id)sender;

-(void)handleTimerTick;

-(void)updateLabel;

@end

@implementation MyController
@synthesize theLabel;

-(IBAction)doCountdown: (id)sender
{
  if (countdownTimer)
  return;


remainingTicks = 60;
[self updateLabel];

countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target: self selector: @selector(handleTimerTick) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];
}

-(void)handleTimerTick
{
remainingTicks--;
[self updateLabel];

if (remainingTicks <= 0) {
  [countdownTimer invalidate];
  countdownTimer = nil;
  }
}

-(void)updateLabel
{
  theLabel.text = [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt: remainingTicks] stringValue];
}


@end
```

So, how can I put `theLabel.text` to label in `NavigationBar`?
I call method `doCountdown` in `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self doCountdown:nil];
```

Where is my fault? If I try to watch theLabel, `NSLog` says `(null)`.

UPD:
And another stupid question. If I try to move label with `NSTimer` to the right, like here:

`[self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Экзамен"];
    self.theLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [self doCountdown:nil];
    UILabel *yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260,6,55,32)];
    yourLabel.text = self.theLabel.text;
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:yourLabel];`

my timer doesn't start, it shows initial time at label and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

The label is null because you don't create it anywhere.

In your viewDidLoad you should create it and add to navigation item's title view, e.g. like this:

```
self.theLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)] autorelease];
self.navigationItem.titleView = self.theLabel;
```

Don't forget to release theLabel in dealloc.

Comment: thanks, I tried to create `theLabel` in `doCountdown` method, and it didn't work. Now with your help my problem fixed. Thanks again!

Comment: If you can, help me with another stupid NSTimer label problem. Added it in first post.